# problem in fb:request-form

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

In the my facebook app  i m using fb request form there i want to  know that user has send friend request to any one or just skip the page.

code is

```
<fb:serverFbml width= "620" style="float:center">
    <script type="text/fbml">
      <fb:fbml>
          <fb:request-form

                    action='<?php echo $config["base_url"]."?action=3;?>' 
                    target="_top"
                    method="POST"
                    invite="true"
                    type="....some thing"

                    content="...some thing"
                    >

                    <fb:multi-friend-selector    target="_top"
                    showborder="false"
                    actiontext="----" rows='4' cols='4' max='1' import_external_friends = "false">
        </fb:request-form>
      </fb:fbml>
    </script>
  </fb:serverFbml>
```

as the developer document says that if user either send the request or skip the request page it will go to action URL . Is there any thing to differentiate between these two case.

Please ignore any English grammar mistake.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're looking for is most likely included in the server response, check it.

Btw, FBML is going to be deprecated very soon, so if this is a new application, you better switch to the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).